# Pinescript Stop not working - Local Scope?

Tags: pine-script, exit, pine-script-v4

I have been trying to toget some entry/exit code working in pinescript (5). It seems to work for the Limit on a strategy.exit, however the stop doesn't trigger.

I've been playing with this but I cant get it to work - I think it may be down to the local ? global scope.

- In essence the entries are fine and work
- Exits type is selected from a drop down and its a set of options-  most like fixed % TP are calculated by the entry price variable entryPriceB.
- BUT, there is a 'Custom'  TP option which is a signal - and so the TakeProfitB variable cannot be calculated until the signal CLOSE_BUY_SIGNAL is recieved.

```
if Trade_Direction_Filter_Long and dateRange and OPEN_BUY_SIGNAL and Long_Orders_Placed < Max_Long_Orders
    entryPriceB := close
    Long_Position := true
    stopLossB := SL ? calculateSL() : na
    takeProfitB := TP ? calculateTP() : na

    if useLeverage 
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, limit=entryPriceB, qty=math.min(math.max(.000001, ( strategy.equity / close ) * leverage), 1000000000), alert_message = alert_txt_entry_long)//ADD {{strategy.order.alert_message}} to the message box in Alerts to set up dynamic link
        Long_Orders_Placed := Long_Orders_Placed + 1
        alert("ADD Increased count - " + str.tostring(Long_Orders_Placed)) 
    else  
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, limit=entryPriceB, alert_message = alert_txt_entry_long)//ADD {{strategy.order.alert_message}} to the message box in Alerts to set up dynamic link
        Long_Orders_Placed := Long_Orders_Placed + 1
        alert("ADD Increased count - " + str.tostring(Long_Orders_Placed)) 

if Trade_Direction_Filter_Long and dateRange and Long_Orders_Placed > 0 
    if CLOSE_BUY_SIGNAL and optionTP == "Custom"
        takeProfitB := TP ? calculateTP() : na
        strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop=stopLossB, limit=takeProfitB, comment = "Signal Exit")
        Long_Orders_Placed := Long_Orders_Placed - 1
    else if (optionTP != "Custom" )
        strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop=stopLossB, limit=takeProfitB, comment = "Option Exit")
        Long_Orders_Placed := Long_Orders_Placed - 1
```

Hope this makes sense, any input would be gratefully received.

Ive tried moving the scope around but run into the issue of exit being conditional based on it being optionTP == "Custom" and CLOSE_BUY_SIGNAL.   or optionTP != "Custom"

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing could be related to the way you're updating the `takeProfitB` value conditionally within the if `CLOSE_BUY_SIGNAL` and `optionTP == "Custom"` block. Pine Script is a forward-looking language, and changing a variable within an if condition may not update the variable in the way you expect. Try the following approach:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Custom TP Example", overlay=true)

var float entryPriceB = na
var bool Long_Position = na
var float stopLossB = na
var float takeProfitB = na
var bool CLOSE_BUY_SIGNAL = ta.crossover(close[1], close)
var string optionTP = "Custom" // Replace with your logic for optionTP

if ta.crossover(close[1], close)
    // Entry conditions
    entryPriceB := close
    Long_Position := true
    stopLossB := SL ? calculateSL() : na
    takeProfitB := optionTP == "Custom" ? calculateTP() : na

if ta.crossover(close, close[1]) and Long_Position
    // Exit conditions
    if optionTP == "Custom"
        takeProfitB := calculateTP()

    strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop=stopLossB, limit=takeProfitB, comment = "Exit")
    Long_Position := false
```

In this modified code:

- I use the `ta.crossover` function to detect `CLOSE_BUY_SIGNAL`. Modify this condition according to your actual signal logic.
- I update `takeProfitB` conditionally both when the position is entered and when you want to exit with a `"Custom" TP`. This ensures that `takeProfitB` is properly set when `CLOSE_BUY_SIGNAL` occurs.
- I use `Long_Position` as a flag to track whether you are in a long position or not. This helps in determining when to exit.

Please adapt the code according to your specific entry and exit conditions, but this structure should help ensure that takeProfitB is calculated correctly when needed. Good luck!